# you will redirect after 5 second in php?

Tags: php

how can i put php code in my page do this -  " After 5 sec shows a link".

I want the whole code in php Only .

ex - in php:

```
if(5 Seconds later )
{
`echo'<a href='google.com'>click here ..</a>';`
}
```

Comment: And how do you plan to let your server change something on the client without client accessing your server? Ain't gonna work. You need to do it in javascript on the client side. Are you okay with javascript? Unless you want to write this link at the very bottom of your page. Then flush() your output, sleep, and echo.

Comment: +1 @Grzegorz PHP doesn't run client side, all you'll do is cause your server to sleep for 5 seconds before it renders your web page and sends it to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sleep then output the link

```
<?php
    flush(); //make sure all other html is written to the client
    sleep(5);
    echo'<a href="google.com">click here ..</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
sleep(5);
echo 'your link';
```

this is [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) for sleep method

Comment: That's `sleep (5);` not `sleep 5;`

Comment: You're welcome. I take it that Ruby helps to reduce the amount of code then?

Comment: yes no need to use () or ; at last, ruby make your code elegant, and it is created for that

Comment: Makes sense. I started getting into Ruby, but couldn't understand it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

> in php: **if**(5 Seconds later)

If it's 5 seconds later, it's after the first request, right ?

So to achieve this, you should use JS client side to countdown (or pure HTML with a meta tag redirect), and store `time()` in a session so that you can check that `$_SESSION - time() > 5`